# Call method when table cell loads

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am quite new to iOS, but am getting along quite well, until tonight!  Here is my problem.  I have a `UITableView` Controller, which I am populating dynamically.  Each cell contains a switch, and a label.  flicking the switch performs an action over the Internet.

This part works fine, but, when the app loads, all of the switches are defaulted to either on or off, what I want to do is :

- Cell Loads
- Cell shows activity indicator
- Cell makes a call to the Internet to determine what state it should be in ( on or off)
- Activity indicator hides

The only bit I cannot work out, is how to assign a "on load" method to the cell, is this even possible?  I have tried using :

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{

}
```

but, whilst this appears to run when the cell loads, I cannot work out how to reference the calls tag ( which I am using as its identifier )

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think You must Write your Mehtod or call it first from  ViewDidload And then check status of your switch and change its as per that... and also put activity indicator untill it wiil not complete its work... or try async or ASIHTTPRequest to make call to internet..